# How to Click on link which has Javascript using Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby, xpath, hyperlink, watir

I am new to Watir and have a scenario which is a blocker for me. I have to click on the below link. It is shown as a link. It is any normal forgot passord?? click here .... option which is there in the application which I am testing. Please advice how to click on this link. I have tried the below mentioned x paths as well but no luck.

```
<a href="javascript:forgot_password()">
```

x paths used with no luck :

```
1> ie.link(:xpath, "//img[@onclick='javascript:forgot_password()']").click
2> ie.link(:xpath,"//a[@href='javascript:forgot_password()']/").text # => "Click Here) "
3> ie.element_by_xpath("//link[contains(@href , 'javascript:forgot_password()')]/").click
```

Comment: If you could show us the HTML source of the link that you're trying to interact with that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if xpath works on your system: appart form watir gem you have to have installed REXML with version greater than 3.1.6.

And i don't know what could be wrong with your code because I don't know which page you are accessing, if you can, please give us the link. Personally I would do something like this, but there may be lots of alternatives.

```
ie.link(:xpath, "//a[contains(@href='javascript:forgot_password')]/").click
```

Comment: Also , I tried this and even thsi work good for me. ie.link(:xpath,"//a[@href='javascript:forgot_password()']/").click

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this?

```
browser.link(:href => "javascript:forgot_password()").click
```

Comment: Zeljko's answer is the one you should try first.  Just make sure you add the colon before :href => or you'll get an error.

Comment: Agreed, avoid using xpath unless it's the only way to solve the problem.  it's harder to make sense of, often brittle, and sometimes slower to parse.

Comment: Hi All, Sorry for late response was out of internet reach. This above solution works for me... Thanks for the same

Comment: Also... I have seen this many time 'avoid using xpath' .. I want to understand why is that. Is going to break after some time or is it that it will not work consistantly ??

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath selectors look quite confused looking at them.

Line one

```
ie.link(:xpath, "//img[@onclick='javascript:forgot_password()']").click
```

intends to find a link, but looks for an image.  Would that ever work?

Try using

```
ie.link(:xpath, "//a[@onclick='javascript:forgot_password()']").click
```

or

```
ie.link(:xpath, "//a[@onclick='javascript:forgot_password()']").fire_event('onclick')
```

It's potentially just not triggering the `onClick` event when using `.click` on an element.  I can't remember whether it does or not.

Without seeing the page, I can't really be certain, but you might not need to be using xpath to find this element at all.

If the text is "Click here" you could use that as the locator instead.

```
ie.link(:text => "Click here").click
```

... or the equivalent `.fire_event('onclick')`

It's incredibly tough to diagnose the problem without seeing the html in question, and accurate Watir being run against it (i.e. copied and pasted directly from your file), so these suggestions are pretty much shots in the dark.